# VBA how to run the code until it reaches the last max function

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, max

I have a code for an array that saves all the data from my spreadsheet in columns D to I, however it also saves all of the blank cells from the sheet too which I don't want. All of the columns have the same number of rows, but ideally I want the array for every row from the second until it finds the last repetition of the max that it works out from column D. My code is:

```
Sub PopulatingArrayVariable()

Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As Long
Dim TotalTargets As Double

TotalTargets = WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("D"))

Set DataRange = Sheets("Result").Range("D:I")

For Each cell In DataRange.Cells
    ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
    myArray(x) = cell.Value
    x = x + 1
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the `max` have to do with your problem? You refer to it in both your question and its title, but the loop that you are asking about doesn't seem to involve it at all. The phrase "the last repetition of the max" suggests that this should somehow or other be involved with the loop -- but how?

Comment: Not really answer to your question but doing `ReDim Preserve` inside loop per step is not considered as good practice. Your intent seems to load non-blank data from column D to I in an array. Is it correct understanding?

Comment: To add to the comment of @shrivallabha.redij -- using `ReDim Preserve` that way makes the complexity quadratic since at each stage you are allocating a new array and copying the old elements. A better strategy is to over-allocate the original array and use a single `ReDim Preserve` afterwards. Alternatively, just use a collection.

Comment: the max comes into the code later but it is also where the last row of data is, is there away so that i can specify the code to work until the last row instead? @JohnColeman

Comment: Something like `Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row` is a standard way to get the last row in column D in the active sheet which contains data. It will give 1 in the event that column D is all blank.

Comment: I'd suggest `lngLastRow = Sheets("Result").Range("D:I").Find("*", Sheets("Result").Range("D1"), , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row` which will locate the last row for specified columns.

Comment: Max can give wrong / misleading results if there are blanks and the MAX doesn't match with filled rows. I have seen `COUNTA` being used for such purpose but there are better ways to get the last row in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach which should skip `ReDim Preserve` altogether.

See if it helps your situation.

```
Sub BuildArray()
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim arList As Object
Dim varOut As Variant

lngLastRow = Sheets("Result").Range("D:I").Find("*", Sheets("Result").Range("D1"), , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
Set arList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each rng In Sheets("Result").Range("D1:I" & lngLastRow)
    If Len(Trim(rng.Value)) > 0 Then
        arList.Add rng.Value
    End If
Next
varOut = arList.ToArray

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition for the length of the cell before adding to the array:

```
For Each cell In DataRange.Cells
    If Len(Trim(Cells)) > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
        myArray(x) = cell.Value
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next cell
```

The `Trim()` would remove the spaces from left and right, thus if there is a cell with just one space like this  it would still give 0 and would not be taken into account.

[Trim MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions)